# Fazer o scroll rolar para o final da página automaticamente

Tags: css3, jsf, front-end, rolamento, xhtml

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde o usuário faz uma pergunta e o servidor entrega uma resposta, estou com o problema em fazer com que a barra de rolagem vá acompanhando a conversa, até o momento estou tendo o histórico da conversa na tela porém tenho que arrastar com o mouse para ver as novas mensagens. Estou utilizando JSF com AJAX .

```
<div id="perguntaResposta">
                <ul class="messages">
                    <h:panelGroup id="dialogo">
                        <ui:repeat var="conversa" value="#{chat.conversas}">
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{conversa.usuario == 1}">
                                <li class="message right appeared">
                                    <div class="avatar"></div>
                                    <div class="text_wrapper">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{conversa.intereacaoFala}" />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{conversa.usuario == 2}">
                                <li class="message left appeared">
                                    <div class="avatar"></div>
                                    <div class="text_wrapper">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{conversa.intereacaoFala}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode forçar o usuário a ir pra o fim da pagina com Javascript:

```
var heightPage = document.body.scrollHeight;
window.scrollTo(0 , heightPage);
```

Caso preciso tirar alguma duvida:
https://jsfiddle.net/lucassilvax/c9L0jn6w/1/

Answer (score -2):

var objDiv = document.getElementById("div_chat");

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("div_chat");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;